# php add ua-parser as a third party to symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

i am really frustrated trying to add [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-php) as a third party lib to my symfony2 project.

i followed [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html).
when i run from the vendor directory

```
composer require ua-parser/uap-php
```

it creates a new vendor directory new folder inside... (is it normal?)
in my controller i wrote

```
use UAParser\Parser;

$parser = Parser::create();
```

but when i do the request i get this error.

> Attempted to load class "Parser" from namespace "UAParser". Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Twig_Parser",
>   "Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\Parser",
>   "Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Parser\Parser",
>   "Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser" or "Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser"?

how can i check if the autoloader loads the class?

Comment: It's ok that composer created new directory for ua parser in vendor directory. It rather means that installation was successful.

Comment: is there any other configuration i need to change / check?

Comment: I just installed ua-parser into one of my Symfony projects and it works fine. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Hey Alex thnx for the help. it was an error memory error in the composer that caused by the amazon micro server